# Help on Rocket Injector Equation

Tags: rockets, propulsion, mathematics, amateur-rocketry, krzycki-text

Hello can someone explain me how can I get the value of (6340) because when I try to solve the given values on the book I get (6423.980075) when I round it off it is still not the right answer can someone help me please [image]

ρ=44.5 lb/ft³ 
g=32.2 ft/sec² 
ΔP=100 convert to lb/ft² = 14400 lb/ft²

My Solution
√(2x32.2)(44.5)(14400)=6423.980075
Please tell me how can I get 6430 instead of 6423 help

Comment: Are you going to addess the concerns raised on your last couple of questions?

Comment: Idk please help me on this one I already figured the other one

Comment: If you already solved out [your first problem](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40563/29766) perhaps you could add your solution as an answer, or mark the existing answer as correct and accepted if it was helpful?

Comment: I had marked the existing answer correct

Comment: 6430 is pretty suspiciously round, given the numbers that allegedly went into it. I expect that the authors have just used some unreasonable rounding somewhere, or a slightly odd value for one of the constants. The final area ends up being within 0.000001in^2 of the given answer.