# Need clarification of units on rocket nozzle equation

Tags: rockets, amateur-rocketry, krzycki-text

I have been working on modeling liquid rocket engines and have read the book How to Design, Build and Test Small Liquid Fuel Rocket Engines, I had a question about the nozzle area and the units involved and I found this post and it helped me get as far as I am, but the units don't make sense.
[Need help on rocket nozzle equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51490/need-help-on-rocket-nozzle-equation)

[image: unit Manipulation]

The unit I end up with is Sqrt(ft) which makes no sense. If it was a unit squared, you could take the square root of it. I am sure I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34711/6944

Comment: Of course the units don't make sense, you're not using metric... :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're looking at the "original post" referenced in the linked post, and trying to work out the units.

[image]

First of all, I'd strongly recommend you learn how to do this in SI units. The ambiguity of the pound and the lack of a true mass unit in the English system is just going to give you heartburn, and as far as I know, all actual engineers use SI anyway today.

Anyway, based on the equation as laid out in the snippet above, they're treating the foot-pounds and the mass in the gas equation as the same kind of pound. If you don't try to convert between lbm and lbf, it comes out correctly.

(ft-lb/lb/degR * degR) / (ft/s^2)

[image]

Do all your cancellation, and you're left with sec^2, so once you do your square root, you'll end up with seconds.

And that makes sense, because the rest of the equation is a flow rate divided by a pressure.  Which is to say:

A = lbs/sec / psi * s

Convert psi into the more proper unit lbs/in^2, do your cancellation, and you end up with in^2, which is what we expect for a nozzle throat measurement.

I can't speak to whether that original poster's equation is valid, but going by what he wrote, that's how it's going to work.

Comment: The *slug* is the mass unit you're missing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(unit)

Comment: I don't think replacing the force-derived pound-mass with a force-derived slug actually changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the original question of how the units work out, this is how.
The equation is

$$A_t=\frac{w_t}{ P_t} \sqrt\frac{RT_t}{\gamma g_c}$$

Now $g_c$ is 32.2 ft-lbf/s$^2$-lbm (rounded numerical value). The units on R are ft-lbf/lbm $deg R$. With no units on $\gamma$, under the square root the units are lbf$^2$s$^2$/lbm$^2$. After taking the square root, the s/lbm cancels the units on $w_t$ and the lbf cancels the pound in pressure leaving square inches from pressure for the unit on area.

Here is a quick derivation of the formula, since the book does not give it and the equation is not really the standard one.

Given flow in the nozzle $$w = \rho V A$$ where V is the flow speed. Use the ideal gas law to eliminate $\rho$, $\rho = P/RT$. The speed of sound is $a=\sqrt{\gamma g_c RT}$. At the throat, $V=a$ so rewrite with subscript t for throat:
$$w_t=\frac{P_t A_t}{RT_t}\sqrt{\gamma g_c RT_t} $$

A little simplification of $\sqrt{ RT_t}$ and solve for $A_t$ gives the first equation in this reply.

A note on the slug: A slug is the mass that accelerates at 1 ft/s$^2$ by a force of 1 pound force (lbf). Therefore, F = ma. When pound force and pound mass are used, force, mass and acceleration are related by
$$F=\frac1{g_c} ma$$.

If you want to use the slug in the first formula, convert $w_t$ in lbm/s to slugs per second, that is, divide it by 32.2. Convert R, given in the text as 65 ft lb/lb degR by multiplying by 32.2 to get 2093 ft lbf/(slug deg R). The $g_c$ is just 1 (no units) and the lbf in R can be replaced by slug ft/s$^2$. You get the same answer, just more work since given quantities are in lbf and lbm system.